# Selenium webdriver: Clicking a legend to fire a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, selenium, navigation, automation, webdriver

I have a page I am trying to automate. When the page loads there is a table with headings, when you click a heading it calls some javascript function and expands the page to reveal some links. This is a section of the code:

```
<fieldset class="fsClosed">
<legend>All orders</legend>
<div class="fieldsetWrapper">
</fieldset>
```

When I manually use this page I click on the text "All orders" and it will expand the page to show more links and options. Can anybody tell me how to do this using selenium? I have tried using the `byLink()` and `byXpath()` but they don't do anything when I call `click()`;

Comment: wat argument u giving inside byXpath()?

Comment: doh my xpath was incorrect! sorry.